# How to use a list in Oracle query from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I have the following query:

```py
SOUTHERN_STATE = ["AL", "GA", "TN", ....]

query = """
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        USERS
    WHERE
        STATE in ({})
""".format(SOUTHERN_STATE)
```

but I got this error: `ORA00936: missing expression`

How can I use a list in an Oracle query in Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [imploding a list for use in a python MySQLDB IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589284/imploding-a-list-for-use-in-a-python-mysqldb-in-clause)

Comment: See the cx_Oracle manual [Binding Multiple Values to a SQL WHERE IN Clause](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause).

Answer (score 4):

The answer supplied by Joe Thor will work well so long as the values in the `SOUTHERN_STATE` variable are well-known and cannot result in SQL injection. If the values are not well-known, this solution can be used instead:

```py
SOUTHERN_STATE = ["AL", "GA", "TN", ....]
bind_names = ",".join(":" + str(i + 1) for i in range(len(SOUTHERN_STATE)))
sql = f"""
    SELECT *
    FROM USERS
    WHERE STATE in ({bind_names})"""
for row in cursor.execute(query, SOUTHERN_STATE):
    print(row)
```

You can see more details about this approach in the [cx_Oracle user documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause).

Comment: That's using python format strings rather than cx_oracle bind parameters and would be unsafe if any of the values came from input.

Comment: Nope, its using bind variables. Note the colon (:) in tthe bind names!

Answer (score 0):

Join the python list into a string and pass the string. Per the comments, using the logic in this post:

[Python cx_Oracle module: unable to format query in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268922/python-cx-oracle-module-unable-to-format-query-in-code)

```
SOUTHERN_STATE = ["AL", "GA", "TN", ....]
SOUTHERN_STATE_STRING ','.join(['%s'] * len(SOUTHERN_STATE))


query = """
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        USERS
    WHERE
        STATE in ({})
""".format(SOUTHERN_STATE_STRING, tuple(SOUTHERN_STATE))
```